How to make a thread run beyond the duration time in Jmeter
I wanted to run the thread for 'n' number of iteration till the duration(6 hours). After 6 hours Jmeter shuts down all the threads . In my case, one of the transaction got started but before the transaction got completed the jmeter shutdown the threads as it reached the configured duration time . Is there a way for the thread to wait till the transaction gets completed ?
Looking for a solution

You can use While Controller to that and instead of setting the test duration in the Thread Group do it in the While Controller.

Put your Samplers which represent the "transaction" under the While Controller

Use the following __groovy() function as the While Controller's condition:
${__groovy((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) < 21600000,)}



This way:

no more new samplers will be executed after 6 hours from test start
all While Controller children will be executed completely (till the last Sampler) so there won't be unfinished transactions

